# Grep backreference questions

Tags: regex, grep

For a text file like:

`there is a blue beach ball`

`there is a green beach ball`

`there is a blue and green beach ball`

`there is a blue and blue beach ball`

- In a Grep backreference command, like `grep -E '(blue|blue).*\1'`, what is the digit `1` referring to?  How would you use `2`, `3`, etc? When I change it to a `2`, I get an error stating: `invalid back reference`
- Why does it only match the last line?
- Why doesn't `grep -E '(blue|green).*\1'` match line # 3?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your regex, `(blue|blue)` is a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html). After a capturing group has captured a group, `\1` can be used to refer to what was captured. (That's why it's called *capturing*: because it holds onto it so you can use it later.)
If you had a second parenthesized capturing group, you could use `\2` to refer to it, or `\3` for a third, and so on.

So the regex matches "blue", then any characters, then "blue" again. That's why it doesn't match the first two lines.

When you change it to `(blue|green)`, it matches either "blue" or "green", then any characters, then *whatever the capturing group matched*. So it matches either of these:

```
there is a blue and blue beach ball
there is a green and green beach ball
```

but it does not match either of these:

```
there is a blue and green beach ball
there is a green and blue beach ball
```

If you want to match those, you will need to use another group (does not matter if it's capturing or not), like this: `grep -E '(blue|green).*(blue|green)'`

Comment: Great answer, thank you for your input!